# updating sharepoint list using wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a wcf web service to update sharepoint list. when i integrated with .net application in my local machine ,its working fine. I have created new .net application in another machine and referred dll in it. all methods which I created in wcf are displaying but while running the application its giving the `request failed with http status 404 not found` .

My code (instance for wcf),

```
WebService_Call.WB_Svc.ServiceCall WebSvcCall = new WebService_Call.WB_Svc.ServiceCall();

 WebSvcCall.ProjectStatusUpdate("sharepointURL", "10", "InProgress", "This Comes from Web Svc", DateTime.Now, true, DateTime.Now,true);
```

Error,

[image]

Any help?

Comment: did you refresh WCF svc reference on new machine ? i suspect copied code+binary retained localhost reference

Comment: Its working :) the mistake i made is, I added service reference instead of web reference. and also changed the localHost to system name.
Thanks & Regards,
Karthi